# How to track if a form has been filled out

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I am working on a powerapps form that collects data, and within this data there are 7 locations that must fill out the form monthly, is there a way to track if they have completed it? And could this be added onto, for example sending out an email to the designated people that should have filled out the form? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Where you are storing the data? If you are storing the data in SharePoint or SQL than you can write a PowerAutomate (Flow) to scan through all the items, and if there is any missing entry than you can send an email to the respective user.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Aakash said yesterday i would submit each data field as an separate item into a SharePoint list.
This way you can use a power automate flow to check how many fields a specific person has submitted or not.

A scheduled flow with a if statement could be used to send out a "3 of 7 locations are missing. Please complete your form" notification by mail or teams chat X days before deadline.

---

Or as alternative use Forms + Power Automate to check if the completed form was submitted

1. In power automate create a new instand cloud flow

[image: screenshot of creating a new instand flow]

2. The trigger we need is not one of the most used. so choose "skip" on the next screen

[image: screenshot skip trigger]

3. in the next screen choose "Microsoft Forms" as trigger to start the flow

[image: screenshot choose Forms as trigger]

4. Choose "When a new response is submitted (so the Flow starts every time a user finishes a Form)

[image: screenshot trigger on submitted form]

5. Choose the Form to use with this flow

[image: screenshot choose Form to use in flow]

6. Just add an action to send out an E-Mail or add an item to a SP list and then use a monthly scheduled flow to check if you have an entry from this person or not

Comment: How would a person use a flow to scan all the fields and see the value of a certain field? The would best apply to my case. Thank you!

Comment: And is the form you discuss above applicable to powerapps forms or microsoft forms only?

Comment: I'm not sure if a get your questions right. I was talking about a form build with MS Forms. This form can be accesses by all persons via a provided link. They see all the Questions/Datafields you defined in MS Forms and will fill it out.
And then you can analyze the answers / or not answers with a power automate flow. 
The value of the answers are provided in the object of the submitted form.
Is this answering your question?

Comment: Or should i provide you an example "using the values send by the form"?